# python's smtplib cannot connect to gmail, mail.ru or anything else

Tags: python, gmail, smtplib

All lines starting from line all return an error Errno 10060 or an error Errno 10061:

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:465')
mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.ru", 25)
mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.ru", 2525)
```

Could you help? I must be missing something trivial... Error messages in full:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 302, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 277, in _get_socket
return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
raise err
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 302, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 277, in _get_socket
return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
raise err
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: Check your firewall and network configuration.

Comment: I might be behind the firewall. Is there any way to check if it is firewall that creates issues? Thanks.

Comment: @lavin: how do I use a proxy?

Comment: @YuccaV: you're most likely either using a banned/restricted IP. If the target machine *actively* refused the connection, you may not be able to connect to that server on that port. you could test on another network/machine to verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with all commands below; my issue is indeed caused by IP restrictions. Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: I asked IT services of my employer to grant me access to one of corporate SMTP servers ...

Answer (score 2):

Use [`smtplib.SMTP_SSL()`](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html?highlight=smtp#smtplib.SMTP_SSL) for a TLS connection.

Comment: server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) does not work, Errno 10060 :(

Answer (score 1):

Or Use `server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:25')` for normal connection

and if you want tls from port 25, simply add

```
server.starttls()
```

after the first line.

ps: since port 25 is default, the following is equivalent:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com')
server.starttls()
```

Comment: :P just an option. if you want tls from port 25, simply add server.starttls()